# Elasticsearch Dynamic Analyzer & synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have a use case where I want my application to dynamically decide on xyz_tokizer, xyz_filter, xyz_synonyms etc

something similar to this
'''
GET test/_search

```
{
  "query":{
    "match": {
      "content": {
          "query": "search_text",
          "analyzer": {
            "filter": "xyz_filter",
            "tokenizer": "xyz_tokenizer"
          }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

'''
However, it throws error. As per elasticsearch docs I found out that we can specify only analyzers that are defined in index settings. Similarly, How to specify filters, tokenizer as well dynamically

Comment: did you get a chance to look at my answer? let me know if yu need further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, these analyzers need to be registered in your index, what you can do is to use the [search time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html), dynamically according to your requirements.

But index-time, you can't add them dynamically, it needs to be present in your index settings. You can also change the index-setting to add the new analyzer and add new fields with the newly added analyzer(incremental changes), but changing the existing analyzer of a field is a breaking change and you need to reindex the whole data.

Comment: okay so based on this a solution that I could come up with is to add all possible combinations of xyz_analyzer in index settings
and during search time use an appropriate analyzer
Not sure if that's the best way to achieve

Comment: @KaushikJ, yeah this is how you need to achieve it and there is no harm in doing that :)